# Problem with a Jquery toggleClass script when hovering

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, frontend

I'm new to the community, also pretty new in this world of web programming, this is the issue that is driving me nuts,

I tried this code to add a class when I hover the ul list element, so I can display the nav element, but instead of open only the hovered dropdown menu, it displays all the ul element with the class I selected.

Here is the Jquery code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("ul").hover(function() {
    $(this)
      .find(".dropdown-list")
      .toggleClass("dropdown-menu");
  });
});
```

and these are the element targered in my html file:

```html
<ul class="header-nav-responsive">
  <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">LAYOUT</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-list">
      <li><a href="#">Topbar</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Header</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Main Menu</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page Title</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page Menu</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sidebars</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Footers</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Options</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Layout Demos</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">FEATURES</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-list">
      <li><a href="#">Topbar</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Header</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Main Menu</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page Title</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page Menu</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sidebars</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Footers</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">ELEMENTS</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-list">
      <li><a href="#">Topbar</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Header</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Main Menu</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page Title</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page Menu</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sidebars</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Footers</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">PAGES</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-list">
      <li><a href="#">Topbar</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Header</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Main Menu</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page Title</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page Menu</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sidebars</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Footers</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">PORTFOLIO</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-list">
      <li><a href="#">Topbar</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Header</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Main Menu</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page Title</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page Menu</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sidebars</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Footers</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">BLOG</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-list">
      <li><a href="#">Topbar</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Header</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Main Menu</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page Title</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page Menu</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sidebars</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Footers</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">SHOP</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-list">
      <li><a href="#">Topbar</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Header</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Main Menu</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page Title</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page Menu</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sidebars</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Footers</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here is the CSS snippet:

```css
.header-nav-responsive .dropdown-list {
    display: none;
}

.header-nav-responsive .dropdown-menu, .nav-icons-big-screen .dropdown-menu {
    flex-direction: column;
    position: absolute;
    align-items: flex-start;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin-top: 11rem;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #e6e8eb;
    box-shadow: 0 14px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}

.header-nav-responsive .dropdown-menu {
    margin-top: -1.1rem;
}

.nav-icons-big-screen i {
    line-height: 80px;
}

.header-nav-responsive:hover .dropdown-menu, .nav-icons-big-screen:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: flex;
    visibility: visible;
}

.header-nav-responsive .dropdown-menu li, .nav-icons-big-screen .dropdown-menu li {
    font-size: 0.8125rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 25px;
}

.header-nav-responsive .dropdown-menu li a, .nav-icons-big-screen .dropdown-menu li a{
    color: #484848;
    padding: 3px 2px;
}

.header-nav-responsive .dropdown-menu li a:hover, .nav-icons-big-screen .dropdown-menu li a:hover {
    color:#2250fc;
    
}
```

At last, you can see how the page display in this link: https://patricio1984.github.io/Polo-template-emulation/

Thanks so much to all in advance! cheers!

Comment: try this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Swati911/0yeg7dm4/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because you are adding the event listener to the ul tag(This includes the parent ul too). Instead, you should have an event listener to the li, say with the class 'menu-item' and toggle the class based on that.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".menu-item").hover(function(){
    $(this).find(".dropdown-list").toggleClass("dropdown-menu");
  });
});
```

Here is the fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/eskcrd3n/

Comment: I used that selector before with the event listener (.dropdown-list), but the toggleClass didn't work, it's like it couldn't be found.

Comment: I think that should work, but there is something else, I guess, that mess up the function :S

Answer (score 1):

Actually your issue here is lies under your main selector. You did go for listening to `ul` whilst you should listen to `li` elements. So whenever you listening to `ul`, the `$(this)` will refer to `<ul class="header-nav-responsive">` so all your elements with class `dropdown-list` will be called for the trigger event.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("li").hover(function() {
    $(this).find(".dropdown-list").toggleClass("dropdown-menu");
  });
});
```

```css
.header-nav-responsive .dropdown-list {
  display: none;
}

.header-nav-responsive .dropdown-menu,
.nav-icons-big-screen .dropdown-menu {
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
  align-items: flex-start;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-top: 11rem;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #e6e8eb;
  box-shadow: 0 14px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}

.header-nav-responsive .dropdown-menu {
  margin-top: -1.1rem;
}

.nav-icons-big-screen i {
  line-height: 80px;
}

.header-nav-responsive:hover .dropdown-menu,
.nav-icons-big-screen:hover .dropdown-menu {
  display: flex;
  visibility: visible;
}

.header-nav-responsive .dropdown-menu li,
.nav-icons-big-screen .dropdown-menu li {
  font-size: 0.8125rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 25px;
}

.header-nav-responsive .dropdown-menu li a,
.nav-icons-big-screen .dropdown-menu li a {
  color: #484848;
  padding: 3px 2px;
}

.header-nav-responsive .dropdown-menu li a:hover,
.nav-icons-big-screen .dropdown-menu li a:hover {
  color: #2250fc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="header-nav-responsive">
  <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">LAYOUT</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-list">
      <li><a href="#">Topbar</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Header</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Main Menu</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page Title</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page Menu</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sidebars</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Footers</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Options</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Layout Demos</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">FEATURES</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-list">
      <li><a href="#">Topbar</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Header</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Main Menu</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page Title</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page Menu</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sidebars</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Footers</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">ELEMENTS</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-list">
      <li><a href="#">Topbar</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Header</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Main Menu</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page Title</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page Menu</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sidebars</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Footers</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">PAGES</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-list">
      <li><a href="#">Topbar</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Header</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Main Menu</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page Title</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page Menu</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sidebars</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Footers</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">PORTFOLIO</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-list">
      <li><a href="#">Topbar</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Header</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Main Menu</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page Title</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page Menu</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sidebars</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Footers</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">BLOG</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-list">
      <li><a href="#">Topbar</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Header</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Main Menu</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page Title</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page Menu</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sidebars</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Footers</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">SHOP</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-list">
      <li><a href="#">Topbar</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Header</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Main Menu</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page Title</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page Menu</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sidebars</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Footers</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**NOTE:** The best way to do this is to use a unique class for your menu titles to avoid any inconsistency.

Comment: Indeed! that was my mistake, I now i could fix it =D thanks for the answer!

Comment: Thanks for the tip, i've read what you share with me and ticked the Harsha answer because it was the first fiddle that I could read and that resolved the issue, but all comments were useful aswell =)

Comment: @patricio1984 Actually his answer and his fiddle are two separate things, his answer obviously will not work because he/she is targeting the wrong element and whilst the fiddle is working correctly it may be edited or deleted after some time, so his answer is not useful and may lead to confusion for other/future members in the community and this is not how SO works. But you are free to choose whatever you want to. 

Comment: @SMAKSS: I will obviously edit the answer to match the fiddle :)

Answer (score 0):

THANKS SO MUCH to both you guys!! the Jsfiddle gave me the right idea, here is the corrected function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".menu-item").hover(function(){
    $(this).find(".dropdown-list").toggleClass("dropdown-menu");
  });
  
});
```

And I added the menu-item class to all my li items!

Thanks!!! problem SOLVED! That was pretty quick =)